# showing executenonquery not initialised error

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int anInteger;
        anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(txtmarks.Text);
        anInteger = int.Parse(txtmarks.Text);
        if (anInteger >= 60)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString =" Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\sakshi\\Documents\\m.accdb";
            con.Open();
           OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();  

           OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            OleDbDataReader rd;

            cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into student(fname,fmarks,fboard)values('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtmarks.Text + "','" + ddlbrd.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'),con");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("u are not elligible");
        }
```

Comment: What is the _complete_ error message exactly? What are your column types? What are your textbox and selecteditem values? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And delete your `adp` and `rd` definitions since you _never_ use them.

Comment: It seems you are missing a portion of your code. You should also read through the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page.

Comment: Do not buyild SQL with striong concatenation. Using parameters will avoid the need to understand the right formatting & quoting for the database; and harden your system against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments on your question, you should look into parameterized queries, but right off it looks like you are not calling the `OleDbCommand` constructor properly.

You have:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into student(fname,fmarks,fboard)values('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtmarks.Text + "','" + ddlbrd.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'),con");
```

Which looks like you closed your string in the wrong place. Try the following instead:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into student(fname,fmarks,fboard)values('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtmarks.Text + "','" + ddlbrd.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')",con);
```

I would change my code to something like the following instead:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(
    "insert into student(fname,fmarks,fboard)values(@fname,@fmarks,@fboard);",
    con
    );

OleDbParameter parmName = cmd.CreateParameter();
parmName.ParameterName = "@fname";
parmName.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
parmName.Value = txtname.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(parmName);

OleDbParameter parmMarks = cmd.CreateParameter();
parmMarks.ParameterName = "@fmarks";
parmMarks.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
parmMarks.Value = txtmarks.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(parmMarks);

OleDbParameter parmBoard = cmd.CreateParameter();
parmBoard.ParameterName = "@fboard";
parmBoard.OleDbType = OleDbType.VarChar;
parmBoard.Value = ddlbrd.SelectedItem.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add(parmBoard);
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on *not initialised* error, looks like you add `con` as a part of your sql command in your `OleDbCommand` constructor, **not** as a second parameter.

Change your

```
+ "'),con");
```

to

```
+ "')", con);
```

But I suggest a few things more;

- You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.
- Delete your `OleDbDataAdapter` and `OleDbDataReader` definitions since you *never* use them.
- Delete your `anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(txtmarks.Text)` line because it is identical with `anInteger = int.Parse(txtmarks.Text)` line.
- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically.
- Open your connection *just* before when you execute your command. Move your `con.Open()` line just before your `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` line.

```
if(int.Parse(txtmarks.Text) > 60)
{
   using(var con = new OleDbConneciton("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\sakshi\\Documents\\m.accdb"))
   using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
   {
      cmd.CommandText = @"insert into student(fname,fmarks,fboard)
                          values(@fname, @fmarks, @fboard)";
      // Add your parameters and their values with Add method and specifing their types
      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```